# How to make a directive refer to a specific row in an array - Angular

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

I am storing a load of button shortcut types in an array of objects. I am trying to write a directive that will return some values depending on the name of the object. Here is my array stored within the controller:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('BtnCtrl', function ($scope) {
    //......rest of controller code here

    $scope.hotKeys = [
        {name: 'primaryTest', keyCode: 49, keyShortcut: "1", funcTriggered: $scope.clickFunction},
        {name: 'secondaryTest', keyCode: 50, keyShortcut: "2", funcTriggered: $scope.clickFunction}
    ]
})
```

In my HTML directive, I want to specify the object using the `name`, and then use values from this object. Here is my attempt at a directive so far:

```
.directive("hotKeyButton", function() {
    return {
        controller: 'BtnCtrl',
        scope: {
            hotKeys: '='
        },
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div class='key-shortcut'>{{hotKeys.keyCode}}</div><div class='hotkey-label'>Button</div>"
    };
})
```

So here you can see I want to use the `keyCode` from the relevant row of the array, but I don't know how to pass in the `name`. Here is my (incorrect) HTML:

```
<button hot-key-button name="secondaryTest" class="po-btn secondary-btn" type="submit"></button>
```

How do I tell my directive to pull data from the `secondaryTest` object?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using an array for your button, I would assume you use `ng-repeat` on your buttons? If this is the case, you can then pass the whole button instead of the name into your directive.

```
<div ng-repeat="button in hotKeys">
  <button hot-key-button hot-key="button" class="po-btn secondary-btn" type="submit"></button>
</div>

.directive("hotKeyButton", function() {
    return {
        controller: 'BtnCtrl',
        scope: {
            hotKey: '=' // you should really use singular here to avoid confusion
        },
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div class='key-shortcut'>{{hotKey.keyCode}}</div><div class='hotkey-label'>Button ({{hotKey.keyShortcut}})</div>"
    };
})
```

Actually you are not suppose to use `<div>` inside `<button>` as per html specification, try to use `<span>` instead, or use a `<div>` to replace the `<button>`.

---

Edit: In case you are not using it like an array, you might want to consider defining your store using key-value instead of array, so you can access specific entry using its name.

```
$scope.hotKeys = {
    'primaryTest': {name: 'primaryTest', keyCode: 49, keyShortcut: "1", funcTriggered: $scope.clickFunction},
    'secondaryTest': {name: 'secondaryTest', keyCode: 50, keyShortcut: "2", funcTriggered: $scope.clickFunction}
}

<button hot-key-button hot-key="hotkeys.primaryTest"></button>

// or use it as a variable
<button hot-key-button hot-key="hotkeys[btnName]"></button>
```

Comment: Good comments...thankyou. I do not want to use a repeater as these buttons could be in various places on the page, they won't necessarily repeat regularly. This is more  a place to store my keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop across the array checking for matches on name. Then you would need to assign the values from the matching record to a specific value on scope and your directive template should be wired up to match that value.

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('BtnCtrl', function ($scope) {
    //......rest of controller code here

    $scope.selectedKeyCode;
    $scope.hotKeys = [
        {name: 'primaryTest', keyCode: 49, keyShortcut: "1", funcTriggered: $scope.clickFunction},
        {name: 'secondaryTest', keyCode: 50, keyShortcut: "2", funcTriggered: $scope.clickFunction}
    ];

    for (i = 0; i < $scope.hotKeys.length; i++) { 
      if ($scope.hotKeys[i].name === $scope.name){
          $scope.selectedKeyCode = row.keyCode;
      }
    }

})

.directive("hotKeyButton", function() {
    return {
    controller: 'BtnCtrl',
    scope: {
        name: '='
    },
    transclude: true,
    template: "<div class='key-shortcut'>{{selectedKeyCode}}</div><div class='hotkey-label'>Button</div>"
};
```

})

Comment: Very clever. For me this still isn't displaying the values - do I need to change the HTML?